# GAE instance hours a lot more than real hours

Tags: google-app-engine

My Java app runs on the Standard Google App Engine (GAE) and is configured to have 1 minimum instance and 1 maximum instance. It is also configured to have 1 minimum idle instance which allows the single instance to run non-stop. I ran a timer for 1 hour and then checked how many instance hours have elapsed. It indicates slightly over 2 hours. How is this possible when only a single instance is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your configuration you should actually be having 2 instances running:

- one resident instance, due to the minimum **idle** instance configuration. This serves only sudden transient traffic peaks while GAE spins up the necessary dynamic instances, see [min-idle-instance on GAE/J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066831/min-idle-instance-on-gae-j/46078629#46078629) and [Why do more requests go to new (dynamic) instances than to resident instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103831/why-do-more-requests-go-to-new-dynamic-instances-than-to-resident-instance/45120896#45120896)
- one dynamic instance, due to the min/max 1 instance configs, handling the regular traffic

Note: the instance class also matters (but probably it's not your case here). From [Standard environment instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing):

> **Important**: When you are billed for instance hours, you will not see any instance classes in your billing line items. Instead, you will
>   see the appropriate multiple of instance hours. For example, if you
>   use an F4 instance for one hour, you do not see "F4" listed, but you
>   see billing for four instance hours at the F1 rate.

Comment: Are you certain that the resident instance is only used for "traffic peaks"? I find no mention of this on their docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed

Comment: Actually that doc states: "However, if you specify a number of minimum idle instances, that specified number of instances run as resident instances while any additional instances are dynamic." - You may be right if you interpreted that text as you've indicated.

Comment: Doing more digging I came across this: "n the new scheduler, however, this isn’t exactly the behavior. Although there’s no longer the concept of “ resident instances” (all instances are dynamic now), the min_idle_instancs flag can still be used:" - https://medium.com/@duhroach/app-engines-new-scheduler-settings-a8a34a1961b2

Comment: @AndroidDev that's an excellent find - I didn't know the new behaviour, you should add an answer with the gist of it. And, if you're able to confirm it in your app's behaviour, make that the accepted answer.